# Запуск скрипта python на Линукс

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

Как запустить скрипт python. В Линукс если он там не установлен, можно ил как с крипт вместе с Питом запускать?По типу как это собирается для windows.

Comment: если в линуксе не установлен python, то это какой то очень странный линукс. В Федора/CentOS на питоне построенн менеджер пакетов, так что там без него ну совсем никак. Если же так оказалось, что его нет, то легче установить через пакетный менеджер, чем использовать какие то третьесортные утилиты.

Comment: Вопрос крайне не понятен. Что значит "по типу, как собирается для windows"? Python интерпретируемый язык. Программы на нём не компилируется и не собираются как на Windows, так и на Linux - они интерпретируются имеющимся интерпретатором Python. В любом хоть сколь-нибудь распространённом дистрибутиве Linux интерпретатор устанавливается по-умолчанию, и в консоли достаточно написать "$ python <путь_к_файлу.py>", чтобы выполнить скрипт. В Windows интерпретатора изначально может и не быть, но он так же легко устанавливается. Возможно, вы ищете что-то подобное https://jenyay.net/Programming/Cxfreeze

Answer (score 1):

Скачиваем\устанавливаем [Nuitka](https://www.nuitka.net/pages/download.html)

Создадим тестовый файл **test.py**

```
def main():
    print("Hello World")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Проверим все ли работает

[image]

Запустим компиляцию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После которой появиться файл **test.bin**

Запустим его

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Зачем было писать ТАК, если можно было просто `print("Hello world!")`? ;D 2. Не надо прилагать текст — скриншотами. 3. Nuitka — не лучший вариант, но это ладно.

Comment: Зачем мне твоя критика, можешь написать лучший ответ. Там же объясни чем "не лучший вариант", всего хорошего